# Django ValueError at /feed/new/

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create the feed part of my social mini social network project. I have a "feed" app which handles all the user posts. Everything works except when I go to submit the post on the user post_form page I get this error:

```
ValueError at /feed/new/
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'User'
```

I'm not really sure what the issue is, but here is my code. Also the traceback doesn't highlight anything, but if you want to see it let me know.

Feed app urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from feed import views

app_name = 'feed'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^new/$',views.CreatePostView.as_view(),name='new_post'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/edit/$',views.UpdatePostView.as_view(),name='edit_post'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/delete/$',views.DeletePostView.as_view(),name='delete_post'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/comment/$',views.add_comment_to_post,name='add_comment_to_post'),
]
```

Feed app Views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404,redirect
from django.utils import timezone
from feed.models import UserPost,UserComment
from feed.forms import PostForm,CommentForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic import (TemplateView,ListView,
                                    DetailView,CreateView,
                                    UpdateView,DeleteView)

# Create your views here.

##Posts Views
class HomeView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    login_url = 'login'
    model = UserPost
    ordering = ['-post_date']

class CreatePostView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    login_url = 'login'
    redirect_field_name = '/userpost_list.html'
    form_class = PostForm
    model = UserPost

class UpdatePostView(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    login_url = 'login'
    redirect_field_name = '/userpost_detail.html'
    form_class = PostForm
    model = UserPost

class DeletePostView(LoginRequiredMixin,DeleteView):
    model = UserPost
    success_url = reverse_lazy('userpost_list')


##Comments Views
def add_comment_to_post(request,pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(UserPost,pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()
            return redirect('userpost_list',pk=userpost.pk)
        else:
            form = CommentForm()
        return render(request,'feed/userpost_list.html',{'form':form})
```

Not sure if you'd need this but here are the Feed app Forms:

```
from django import forms
from feed.models import UserPost,UserComment

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = UserPost
        fields = ('title','post_body')

        widget = {
            'title':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'post-title'}),
            'post_body':forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'post-body'}),
        }

class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = UserComment
        fields = ('comment_body',)

        widgets = {
            'comment_body':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'comment-body'}),
        }
```

Feed app models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.conf import settings

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()

# Create your models here.
class UserPost(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='userpost',default='User')
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150,blank=False)
    post_body = models.TextField(max_length=1000,blank=False)

    def publish(self):
        self.save()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('index')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class UserComment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('feed.UserPost',related_name='comments')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='usercomment')
    comment_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    comment_body = models.TextField(max_length=500)

    def publish(self):
        self.save()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("userpost_list")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your models - the string `'User'` is not a valid user.

```
class UserPost(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='userpost', default='User')
```

The simplest fix is to remove the default:

```
class UserPost(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='userpost')
```

However, unless you set `null=True`, you will then get errors in your `CreatePostView` because you are creating a post without setting the user. You can fix this by overriding `form_valid` and setting the author to `self.request.user` before the form is saved:

```
class CreatePostView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    login_url = 'login'
    redirect_field_name = '/userpost_list.html'
    form_class = PostForm
    model = UserPost

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super(CreatePostView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: I'm now getting an integrity Error: `IntegrityError at /feed/new/
NOT NULL constraint failed: feed_userpost.author_id`

Comment: You need to set the `author` in the `form_valid` method -- I originally had `user` by mistake.

Comment: That worked. Would it be possible to explain to me what's going on that all that happened and why that worked? I've used this code before and it worked, but obviously something about was different from what I had before.

Comment: Which part of the answer do you not follow? I tried to explain step by step why you had to make changes, starting with the invalid `default='User'`.

Comment: I was confused on why I needed to use `author` rather than `user` but I just looked back at the project I took the code from and I see that my model field was called user before so that makes sense. Why did I need to remove default? The reason I had it there was because it prompted me to add it during the migration. Also on my other project I didn't need the `form.instance` and here I do? the code is the same so why might that be?

Comment: Your default was invalid. A foreign key holds the id of the related object -- the string `'User'` is not a valid id. You didn't have to remove the default. You could set it to the id of a user e.g. `1`, but that probably isn't what you want, so I showed you how to set the user in the view. I don't know what the code was like in your other project, so I can't explain why you didn't have to set `form.instance.author` there.